# Why is `data` empty in nested serializer validate method?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework. I have a parent serializer class like so:

```
class MyParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

  # Use custom serializer as a field.
  my_field = MyFieldSerializer(
      required=False,
  )

  name = serializers.Charfield()
}

  def validate(data):
    # validation logic
```

And then my child serializer that is used above looks like this:

```
class MyFieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    email_address = serializers.ListField(
        required=False,
        child=serializers.CharField(),
    )

    phone_number = serializers.ListField(
        required=False,
    )

    def validate(self, data):
        data <-- <-- This is empty if I pass in random invalid data!
        check_for_undefined_fields(self.data, self.fields)
        return data
```

Now, I pass the following data:

```
{
  "my_field": { "invalid_field": "foo"},
  "name": "bar"
}
```

However, if I check `data` in the `validate` method in my `MyFieldSerializer` class during validation, IT'S EMPTY!

Why? How can I fix this so that `data` is actually the data I passed?

Answer (score 2):

Only fields which you have declared will be available in `validate` or `is_valid` or `create` methods. If you need to access those fields, you can use `self.initial_data`.

Comment: So how do I make sure that no undefined fields are passed in my child serializer?

Comment: You will have to do this in your parent serializer validate method.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `ModelSerializer` so every field in request have to be added in `Serializer`. In you case you just have to define `invalid_field`

```
  class MyFieldSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    email_address = serializers.ListField(
        required=False,
        child=serializers.CharField(),
    )

    phone_number = serializers.ListField(
        required=False,
    )
    invalid_field = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        data <-- <-- This is empty if I pass in random invalid data!
        check_for_undefined_fields(self.data, self.fields)
        return data
```

Comment: But this means if I pass `invalid_field` it will work but if I pass `invalid_field_foo` or any other string then it wont work. Which is what I want it to validate -> If any field other than the ones defined is encountered then throw an error,

Answer (score 0):

In the nested serializer, you might be writing the nested field in create which you have set to read_only=True. Change that to read_only=False will solve the problem.

For e.g:
question_response = QuestionResponseSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

Change this to:
question_response = QuestionResponseSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)